# AngularJS - Prevent focus to next input field until validation successful is not working in ie11 and firefox

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11, angular-material

I have written a angularjs function to - "restrict the focus of the cursor in that particular input field until validation is successful", I called the function in "ng-blur". It is working in chrome, but its not working in ie11 and firefox.

In ie11 the focus keeps jumping here and there and the browser hangs, where as in firefox it just simply goes to next field even though the validation fails.

Here's my html code:

```
<form name="userForm">
<md-input-container class="md-block">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input ng-model="firstname" id="firstName" class="firstName" name="firstName" ng-trim="false" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\_]*$/" ng-blur="inputValidation(userForm.firstName.$valid,$event)">
          <div ng-messages="userForm.firstName.$error" ng-if="userForm.firstName.$touched">
                <p ng-message="required" class="ngmText">First Name is required.</p>
                <p ng-message="minlength" class="ngmText">First Name is too short.</p>
                <p ng-message="maxlength" class="ngmText">First Name is too long.</p>
                <p ng-message="pattern" class="ngmText">First Name should contain only alphabets.</p>
            </div>
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container class="md-block">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input ng-model="lastname" id="lastName" class="lastName" name="lastName" ng-trim="false" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\_]*$/" ng-blur="inputValidation(userForm.lastName.$valid,$event)">
          <div ng-messages="userForm.lastName.$error" ng-if="userForm.lastName.$touched">
                <p ng-message="required" class="ngmText">Last Name is required.</p>
                <p ng-message="minlength" class="ngmText">Last Name is too short.</p>
                <p ng-message="maxlength" class="ngmText">Last Name is too long.</p>
                <p ng-message="pattern" class="ngmText">Last Name should contain only alphabets.</p>
            </div>
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container class="md-block">
        <label>Contact No</label>
        <input ng-model="contactno" id="contactNo" class="contactNo" name="contactNo" ng-trim="false" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="10" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" ng-blur="inputValidation(userForm.contactNo.$valid,$event)">
          <div ng-messages="userForm.contactNo.$error" ng-if="userForm.contactNo.$touched">
                <p ng-message="required" class="ngmText">Contact No is required.</p>
                <p ng-message="pattern" class="ngmText">Contact No should contain only numbers.</p>
                <p ng-message="minlength" class="ngmText">Contact No is too short.</p>
                <p ng-message="maxlength" class="ngmText">Contact No is too long.</p>
            </div>
</md-input-container>

</form>
```

my apps.js:

```
var app=angular.module('myApp','ngMaterial','ngAria','ngAnimate','ngMessages']);

app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope,$window){

$scope.inputValidation = function(valid,event){
if(valid==false){

    //$window.alert(valid);
    //$window.alert(event.target.id);

    var element = $window.document.getElementById(event.target.id);
    element.focus();

    //$('#'+event.target.id).focus();
    //event.preventDefault();
    }       
};
});
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, Kindly help me to find a solution for this problem, the focus should not go to the next field when pressing tab or placing the mouse over the other field, not even for a sec until the validation is successful as it works in chrome currently, check out the plunk for this code here http://plnkr.co/edit/2Kn7RcP08u8japSzHWra

Thanks...